# how can i replace character in a string?

Tags: python, spyder

hi i'm trying to simulate what the user might type for one word i.e hello so basically  I have it printed out to the terminal _ _ _ _ _  and I want to replace the "_" with lets say "l" and match where it is in the string,here is my code

```
import re
str1="hello"
lettercheck="l"
a=re.search(lettercheck,str1)
span=(a.span())
print(span)
print(str1[span[0])
count=0
ab="_"
for char in str1:
    print(ab,end=" ")
    if lettercheck==char
    count +=1
    replacechar=str1.replace(ab,str1[span[0]])
    print(replacechar)
```

which prints out
_ _ _ hello
_ hello
_
can anyone explain where I went wrong here and what can I do to fix it? note the count is just for how times how to time the letter  recurrences which  i will work on later on my code this is just an example to try to understand what is going on

Comment: The code you posted does not print out anything it has many syntax errors

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with input and required output.

Comment: fixed syntax@ErikMcKelvey

Comment: input will be a string i have a list of strings which I call randomly for the required output for the example above would be _ _ l l _ @SakshiSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the searching and replacing can be simplified. The regex library is not needed here:

```py
str1 = 'hello'
lettercheck = "l"

positions = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(str1) if char == lettercheck]

for i in range(len(str1)):
    if i in positions:
        print(lettercheck, end='')
    else:
        print('_', end='')
```

returns:

```
__ll_
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
import re
str1 = 'hello'
specific_char = 'l'
print(re.sub(r'[^'+specific_char+']', '_', str1))
```

This will replace everything other than the specific character (eg. l) with an underscore '_'.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simpler and more efficient way to replace every char with "_" other then the specified character.

```
str1 = 'hello'
lettercheck = "l"
result = ""
for i in range(len(str1)):
    if str1[i] != lettercheck:
        result += '_'
    else:
        result += lettercheck
print(result)
```